# Response.End causing System.Threading.ThreadAbortException

Tags: c#, asp.net, response, epplus

I have a try catch in a button_Click() method where I use EPPlus to save some data to an Excel spreadsheet.

```
try 
{
 .... Some calculations here...
   //Create Excel output.
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Report " +
                                   DateTime.Today.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Today.Month.ToString() + "-" +
                                   DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.Hour + "-" +
                                   DateTime.Now.Minute + "-" + DateTime.Now.Second + ".xlsx");
                package.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.End();
}

cach()
{
   LogException();
}
```

I get an error System.Threading.ThreadAbortException, which I get because of Response.End() above, I get that.

What is really annoying is that despite that on my dev machine it still outputs the file but when I place the website on the server, it logs the error, the page keeps loading infinitely and never spits out the file.

Anyone have an idea what is going wrong there?

Comment: 1) are you using `async` and `await`?  2) did you already send a response in the calculations?

Comment: `Response.End()` always throws a `ThreadAbortException` because the current thread responsible for processing http response message is immediately aborted after the `End` method is called.

Comment: No await or async used.

Comment: Is the button inside an update panel? You will have to add it as a trigger if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just catch `ThreadAbortException` and do nothing. You can safely ignore this exception.

EDIT:
Get rid of the log, or add a check to not log on `ThreadAbortException`

```
catch(Exception ex){
    if (ex is System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
    {
        //do nothing
        return;
    }else{
        LogException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I did on mine too, there was no way something was really wrong on Response.End. It is something that happens sometimes, and Microsoft is trying to figure out why, from what I read.

Comment: So the error is not the issue, I can handle that. The fact that my file is not presented to the user is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

When Response.Redirect or Response.End is in a try block, the code in the catch block is executed.

You can catch and absorb this TreadAbortException.

You could also consider adding a finally block that ends the response instead of having it in the try. If you catch an exception you could amend the response and send back an error to the client.